# Access VBA Alphabetically Sorting Filenames appended with Letters of the Alphabet

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting

I have a file structure where duplicate files are appended with letters of the alphabet. For example, if File.txt already exists, than File-A.txt is created.

I need to load the list of all files of a certain name into an array and sort such that Arr(25) is the alphabetically last filename (I.E. Arr(25)=File-Z.txt) and I have the following sort algorithm, but it always alphabetizes such that File.txt is the last element in the array.

```
If filepath <> "" Then
    Do Until filepath = ""
        myArray(i) = filepath
        filepath = Dir
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End If

'Alphabetize
  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    For y = x To UBound(myArray)
      If UCase(myArray(y)) < UCase(myArray(x)) Then
        TempTxt1 = myArray(x)
        TempTxt2 = myArray(y)
        myArray(x) = TempTxt2
        myArray(y) = TempTxt1
      End If
     Next y
  Next x
```

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing the *entire filename*. The reason `file.txt` sorts before `file-a.txt` is because it is checking character by character and exits as soon as it finds an ASCII value in the first file that is higher than the corresponding ASCII value in the second file.  I this particular case, `file.txt < file-a.txt` returns `False` as soon as it compares position 5 because `.` is ASCII 46 and `-` is ASCII 45.

Assuming that you only care about `.txt` files, the solution is to compare the files without the extensions.  You can either use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to do this (which would make reading the directory easier too)...

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    'Alphabetize
    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        For y = x To UBound(myArray)
            If UCase$(.GetBaseName(myArray(y))) < UCase$(.GetBaseName(myArray(x))) Then
                TempTxt1 = myArray(x)
                TempTxt2 = myArray(y)
                myArray(x) = TempTxt2
                myArray(y) = TempTxt1
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End With
```

...or you can use `Left$`:

```
'Alphabetize
For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    For y = x To UBound(myArray)
        If UCase$(Left$(myArray(y), Len(myArray(y)) - 4)) < _
           UCase$(Left$(myArray(x), Len(myArray(x)) - 4)) Then
            TempTxt1 = myArray(x)
            TempTxt2 = myArray(y)
            myArray(x) = TempTxt2
            myArray(y) = TempTxt1
        End If
    Next y
Next x
```